# how to create a request with ASIHttpRequest like the following?

Tags: iphone, ios, networking, youtube, asihttprequest

I was woking on YouTube Resumable Uploads:
https://developers.google.com/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_protocol_resumable_uploads#Sending_a_Resumable_Upload_API_Request

I failed to create a request with ASIHttpRequest like the following.
How to make it work? Thanks! Any help will be appreciated!

(1)

```
POST /resumable/feeds/api/users/default/uploads HTTP/1.1
Host: uploads.gdata.youtube.com
Authorization: Bearer ACCESS_TOKEN
GData-Version: 2
X-GData-Key: key=adf15ee97731bca89da876c...a8dc
Content-Length: 0
Slug: my_file.mp4
```

(2)

```
POST /resumable/feeds/api/users/default/uploads HTTP/1.1

Host: uploads.gdata.youtube.com

Authorization: Bearer ACCESS_TOKEN
GData-Version: 2
X-GData-Key: key=adf15ee97731bca89da876c...a8dc
Content-Length: 1941255
Slug: my_file.mp4
Content-Type: application/atom+xml; charset=UTF-8

<?xml version="1.0"?>
<entry xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom"
  xmlns:media="http://search.yahoo.com/mrss/"
  xmlns:yt="http://gdata.youtube.com/schemas/2007">
  <media:group>
    <media:title type="plain">Bad Wedding Toast</media:title>
    <media:description type="plain">
      I gave a bad toast at my friend's wedding.
    </media:description>
    <media:category
      scheme="http://gdata.youtube.com/schemas/2007/categories.cat">People
    </media:category>
    <media:keywords>toast, wedding</media:keywords>
  </media:group>
</entry>
```

Here is my code for the (2) ,the request finished without error, but the responseData is empty.I don't know why!

```
    NSURL *uploadUrl = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://uploads.gdata.youtube.com/resumable/feeds/api/users/default/uploads"]];
    ASIFormDataRequest *theRequest = [ASIFormDataRequest requestWithURL:uploadUrl];

    NSString *xmlStr = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"<?xml version=\"1.0\"?>\n"
                        @"<entry xmlns=\"http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom\"\n"
                        @"xmlns:media=\"http://search.yahoo.com/mrss/\"\n"
                        @"xmlns:yt=\"http://gdata.youtube.com/schemas/2007\">\n"
                        @"<media:group>\n"

                        //Title
                        @"<media:title type=\"plain\">%@</media:title>\n"
                        //Description
                        @"<media:description type=\"plain\">\n"
                        @"%@\n"
                        @"</media:description>\n"
                        //Category
                        @"<media:category\n"
                        @"scheme=\"http://gdata.youtube.com/schemas/2007/categories.cat\">Entertainment\n"
                        @"</media:category>\n"
                        //Keywords
                        @"<media:keywords>Camera,PowerCam</media:keywords>\n"

                        @"</media:group>\n"
                        @"</entry>\n",        @"PowerCam.mov",@"description" ];


    [theRequest setTimeOutSeconds:60];
    [theRequest addRequestHeader:@"Authorization"   value:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Bearer %@",_oauth.accessToken]];
    [theRequest addRequestHeader:@"GData-Version"   value:@"2"];
    [theRequest addRequestHeader:@"X-GData-Key"     value:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"key=%@", YouTuDevkey]];
    [theRequest addRequestHeader:@"Content-Length"  value:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",xmlStr.length]];
    [theRequest addRequestHeader:@"Slug"            value:@"PowerCam.mov"];  
    [theRequest addRequestHeader:@"Content-Type"    value:@"application/atom+xml; charset=UTF-8"];

    [theRequest appendPostData:[xmlStr dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [theRequest setUploadProgressDelegate:self];
    theRequest.delegate = self;
    theRequest.tag = eWSKYouTubeSharerUploadingVideoMetadata;
    self.requestTag = eWSKYouTubeSharerUploadingVideoMetadata;
    self.request = theRequest;
    [[ASIManager manager] addRequest:theRequest];
    [[ASIManager manager] startQueue];
```

Comment: How exactly isn't it working? Can you post your `ASIHTTPRequest` code?

Comment: Problem solved! The code works fine. The API response is in the headers, so the responseData is empty:)

Comment: Good work :-) Don't forget to post your answer below, then you can accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The example below shows a sample API response to a request to upload video metadata for a resumable upload:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Location: http://uploads.gdata.youtube.com/resumableupload/AF8GKF...0Glpk0Aw
Date: Fri, 04 Dec 2009 16:14:30 GMT
Pragma: no-cache
Expires: Fri, 01 Jan 1990 00:00:00 GMT
Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate
Content-Length: 0
Content-Type: text/html
```

The code works fine. The "Location" url is in the headers, not in the body, so the responseData is empty:)

Answer (score 0):

See [the ASIHTTPRequest how-to](http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/How-to-use) for information on how to use it. Roughly, you will have something like this:

```
ASIHTTPRequest *request = [ASIHTTPRequest requestWithURL:url];
[request addRequestHeader:@"X-GData-Key" value:@"adf15ee97731bca89da876c...a8dc9"];
// add the other special headers as well
NSString *xmlBody = // create the XML data in the body
[request appendPostData:[xmlBody dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[request startSynchronous];
```

Assuming you want to do a synchronous request from a background thread.